# IOS How can I put a remove ads button over a revmob fullscreen ad when it shows?

Tags: ios, iphone, revmob

I am relatively new to objective-c but have built a few small apps. I implemented a revmob fullscreen ad in my app and would like to have a "remove ads" button next to the "X" to capture their attention at the right moment. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can do that, as ad providers need to guarantee you're not hiding the ad from the customers. And if you *could* do it, it might be against your ad contract.

Comment: yeah that would make sense

Comment: If at some point you decide this is in fact the answer to your question, you should click the checkmark to let the system know that your question is answered. Leaving it for a while to see if anyone else answers makes sense, too.

Comment: Thanks will do, I will wait a couple more days to see if there are any other inputs before deciding